# Preventing printf from spamming the console while getting user input

Tags: c++, c, windows, console

I am coding a console application on windows.
I made it multithreaded so it can print status to console while I am receiving input from the prompt.

But when printf() gets called while I am typing the command, I see the output intersecting with what I have typed.

How can I get around this problem? is there a way to keep the input line separate?

I am using getline(cin, strcommand); to collect input data

Comment: Are you outputting newline at the end of the output string (because `stdout` is line buffered) ?

Answer (score 0):

standard output is a mutual exclusive resource, so it cannot be both used by input and output at the same time.

In your problem, input and output intersect with each other, so i think you can use a buffer to store your log created by the  print status thread while you are inputting. When input is over, you can check if there are logs not yet be printed.

```
while(cin >> x) {
  //get output buffer mutex
  if(log_exist)
     //print the log
     //clear the flags
  //release output buffer mutex
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thingk you just need to end the line with << endl; at the end of your cout. then the input will be under the output.